# How to print barcodes containing letters

Tags: barcode, visual-foxpro, foxpro, barcode-printing, code128

How to print codes

E27H, D18H, F28G, J16H, E19G, G29F, I19F, K09F, L18F

as barcodes from Visual FoxPro application.
I tried code below with Code 128 font but barcodes for those codes are created incorrectly:

```
StrTo128B('D18H') appears as D18 in printer bar code
StrTo128B('F28G') appears as  228
StrTo128B('J16H') appears as J16
```

It looks like if StrTo128B() result contains chr(81) and some other characters, those will not appear in output file:

[image]

Other bar codes are printed correctly. Use font script is not chacked:

[image]

```
* Converts a string to be printed with
* True Type Font "PF Barcode 128"
* Numerics and alphabetic (upper and lower case)
* If a character is not valid it is replaced by a space
* USE: _StrTo128B('Codigo 128 B')
* RETURNS: Character

* http://www.portalfox.com/index.php?name=News&file=article&sid=2600
FUNCTION StrTo128B(tcString)
  LOCAL lcStart, lcStop, lcRet, lcCheck, ;
    lnLong, lnI, lnCheckSum, lnAsc
  lcStart = CHR(104 + 32)
  lcStop = CHR(106 + 32)
  lnCheckSum = ASC(lcStart) - 32
  lcRet = tcString
  lnLong = LEN(lcRet)
  FOR lnI = 1 TO lnLong
    lnAsc = ASC(SUBS(lcRet,lnI,1)) - 32
    IF NOT BETWEEN(lnAsc,0,99)
      lcRet = STUFF(lcRet,lnI,1,CHR(32))
      lnAsc = ASC(SUBS(lcRet,lnI,1)) - 32
    ENDIF
    lnCheckSum = lnCheckSum + (lnAsc * lnI)
  ENDFOR
  lcCheck = CHR(MOD(lnCheckSum,103) + 32)
  lcRet = lcStart + lcRet + lcCheck + lcStop
  *--- Esto es para cambiar los espacios y caracteres invalidos
  lcRet = STRTRAN(lcRet,CHR(32),CHR(232))
  lcRet = STRTRAN(lcRet,CHR(127),CHR(192))
  lcRet = STRTRAN(lcRet,CHR(128),CHR(193))
  RETURN lcRet
ENDFUNC
```

Comment: Use FoxBarCode: https://github.com/VFPX/FoxBarCode

Comment: Where to find sample how to use FoxBarCode in report? Its samples are only for using in forms and creating files.

Comment: The Git Repository includes a Reports folder. I haven't used this tool, but seems like what you want should be there.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. You can write this as answer. It is interesting why report does not output some characters.